# Find all objects in array that match IDs of other array - mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm looking for the solution since yesterday, but can't find it. I tried different approaches like `$elemMatch`, aggregation etc. but nothing works. Either I get all objects or just the first one, but never only that ones with the matching IDs.

**What I try to achieve:** Get all objects of an array with one of multiple IDs.

First parameter is the user ID like `60a3f7d0f988f1e57212a81e`. Every Document in this collection is unique by the user ID.

Second parameter is an array like `['609d1cfe0806daba1b0502bf', '609d1bba887035b9cd4292aa']` that consists of different IDs to be matched with the objects of the array `words`.

**My approach gets only the first object and doesn't even work with an array of IDs (wordIDs) as parameter.**

```
Words.prototype.getSpecificPersonalWords = async function(userID, wordIDs) {
const words = await personalWords.aggregate([
        {$match: 
            {"user_id": userID}
        },
        {$unwind: 
            {"path": "$words"}
        },
        {$match: 
            {"words.word_id": { $in: ['609d1cfe0806daba1b0502bf', '609d1bba887035b9cd4292aa'] } }
        }
    ])

return words
}
```

**Document, that I want to query:**

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60a3f7d0f988f1e57212a81e"
    },
    "user_id": "609d22188ea8aebac56f9dc3",
    "__v": {
        "$numberInt": "0"
    },
    "words": [{
        "word_id": "609d1bba887035b9cd4292aa",
        "last_practiced": "2021-05-15 16:00:00",
        "strength": {
            "$numberInt": "1"
        }
    }, {
        "word_id": "609d1c35861d99b9effc0027",
        "last_practiced": "2021-05-15 16:00:00",
        "strength": {
            "$numberInt": "1"
        }
    }, {
        "word_id": "609d1dcbc99e8dba538208d7",
        "last_practiced": "2021-05-15 16:00:00",
        "strength": {
            "$numberInt": "1"
        }
    }]
}
```

**Schema of that document**

```
{
    user_id: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    words: Array
});
```

I hope someone can help me to figure this out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$match` both `user_id` and `word_id` conditions
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `words` and match condition id `word_id` in array of ids

```
const words = await personalWords.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "user_id": "609d22188ea8aebac56f9dc3",
      "words.word_id": {
        $in: ["609d1cfe0806daba1b0502bf", "609d1bba887035b9cd4292aa"]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      words: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$words",
          cond: {
            $in: [
              "$$this.word_id",
              ["609d1cfe0806daba1b0502bf", "609d1bba887035b9cd4292aa"]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w3xFEl-Nued)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I still get only one object back. I need to get every object of the words array that matches an ID of the parameter wordIDs.

Comment: can you check your data, there is only one matching object.. so it is returning only one object..

Comment: My bad, didn't adjust the IDs in the parameter. Thanks a lot!